# Template erro ao retornar valor

Tags: c++, template, gcc

Estou implementando uma classe que representa uma matriz usando template e alocação dinâmica. Porém, quando foi fazer a sobrecarga do operador +(adição) ocorreu o seguinte erro de compilação(somente quando tento somar os objetos ocorre o erro).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
template<typename T>
Matriz<T> Matriz<T>::operator+(const Matriz<T> & sum)
{
     if(linha != sum.linha || coluna != sum.coluna)
    {
       throw std::domain_error("The number of rows and columns must be equal");
    }
    else
    {
       Matriz<T> temp(linha, coluna);
       for(size_t i = 0; i < linha ; i++)   
       {
           for(size_t j = 0; j < coluna; j++)   
           {
              temp[i][j] = ptr[i][j] + sum[i][j];
           }
       }
     return temp;
     }
}
```

Matriz.h

```
template<typename T>
class Matriz
{
    //sobrecarga dos operadores padrão de entrada e saida
    friend std::ostream &operator<< <T>(std::ostream &, const Matriz<T> &);
    friend std::istream &operator>> <T>(std::istream &, Matriz<T> &);

public:
    //construtor. Pode atirar a exceção bad_alloc. 
    explicit Matriz(const size_t = 0, const size_t = 0);
    //destruidor
    virtual ~Matriz();
    //construtor da copia. Pode atirar a exceção bad_alloc  
    explicit Matriz(const Matriz<T> &);
    //Move constructor
    explicit Matriz(Matriz<T> &&);

    T & at(const size_t, const size_t);
    T at(const size_t, const size_t) const;

    T* operator[](const size_t);
    const T * const operator[](const size_t ) const;

    Matriz<T> operator+(const Matriz<T> &);
    //sobrecarga do operador de atribuição. Pode atirar a exceção bad_alloc
    const Matriz<T> &operator=(const Matriz<T> &);
    const Matriz<T> &operator=(Matriz<T> &&);
    //retorna true somente se todos os elementos das matrizes
    //forem iguais. Se não retorna false.
     bool operator==(const Matriz<T> &) const;
     //retorna true se as matriz forem iguais se não retorna false
     bool operator!=(const Matriz<T> &a) const
     {
         return !(*this == a);  
     }

private:
     T ** ptr;
     size_t linha;
     size_t coluna;
};
```

Construtor de cópia:

```
 template<typename T>
 Matriz<T>::Matriz(const Matriz<T> &a)
    :linha(a.linha), coluna(a.coluna)   
 {
    if(a.ptr != nullptr)
    {
        ptr = new T *[linha];
        size_t i;
        try // aloca espaço para a matriz
        {
            for(i = 0; i < coluna ; i++)    
            {
                ptr[i] = new T[coluna];
            }
        }
        catch(...)  // caso não acha espaço
        {
            for(size_t j = 0; j < i ; j++)
                delete [] ptr;
            throw std::bad_alloc();
        }

        for(size_t i = 0; i < linha ; i++) // copia os elementos
        {
             for(size_t j = 0; j < coluna; j++) 
             {
                   ptr[i][j] = a.ptr[i][j];     
             }
        }
    }//fim do if
    else
    {
       linha = 0;
       coluna = 0;
       ptr = nullptr;
   }
}
```

Um caso onde o erro ocorre é o código seguinte:

```
Matriz<int> matriz1;
Matriz<int> matriz2;
matriz1 + matriz2;
```

Comment: Você chegou a implementar o [construtor de cópia](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19167201/copy-constructor-of-template-class)?

Comment: Sim, eu implementei o construtor de cópia. Ele poderia estar causando o erro de alguma forma ? Estou tentando resolver isso dez de ontem, mas não estou tendo muito sucesso =/. Vou editar a pergunta e vou colocar tudo que esta implementando na classe. Já testei os métodos e não encontrei nem um problema.

Comment: Imagino que sim, dado que o erro parece acontecer justamente nele ("*no matching*" parece indicar que não encontrou o construtor de cópia apropriado).

Comment: (*educated guess* aqui): você tentou tirando o `explicit` do construtor de cópia? Talvez a dificuldade esteja ai. Mais info [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480545/explicit-copy-constructor) e [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153527/explicit-copy-constructor-behavior-and-pratical-uses)

Comment: Você tem razão. Retirei o explicit e é código funcionou. Muito obrigado pela ajuda, acho que eu nunca ia pensar que o problema podia ser o explicit. Eu nem lembrava que ele esta lá para falar a verdade. Muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Que bom que era isso. :) Eu coloquei como resposta então.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é o uso do `explicit` na definição do construtor de cópia.

Essa cláusula existe para evitar que o compilador faça conversões (*casting*) implícitos que, muito embora possam ser úteis muitas vezes, as vezes são indesejáveis. Considere esse exemplo ([tirado desta questão no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean)):

```
class Foo
{
    public:
      // construtor com um único parâmetro, pode ser usado em conversão implícita
      Foo (int foo) : m_foo(foo) 
      {
      }

      int GetFoo() { return m_foo; }

    private:
      int m_foo;
};

void DoBar (Foo foo)
{
    int i = foo.GetFoo();
}

int main ()
{
    DoBar(42);
}
```

Como a classe `Foo`, esperada na chamada do método `DoBar`, tem um construtor que espera um inteiro, o compilador é capaz de fazer a conversão do valor [`42`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Pergunta_Fundamental) *implicitamente* para uma instânica da classe `Foo` chamando esse construtor. Se você usar a cláusula `explicit` no construtor, esse comportamento vai ser impedido durante a compilação, e a única forma possível vai ser realmente passando uma referência explícita para a classe: `DoBar(Foo(42))`.

No seu caso, a implementação do operador de soma retorna uma cópia de uma instância interna da classe em `return temp;`, que portanto não se trata de uma inicialização direta. Como o seu construtor de cópia foi declarado como explícito, o compilador trata isso como um erro porque não permite a conversão implícita de um `Matriz<int>` (a variável `temp`) para um `const Matriz<int> &` (o que é esperado pelo único construtor de cópia disponível). Logo, a solução mais simples é remover a cláusula `explicit` da declaração do construtor.

Mais detalhes da justificativa desse comportamento pode ser encontrado [nesta resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4154213/2896619).